# Android build tools 23.0.3 UnsatisfiedLinkError for prebuilt .so files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

After build tools to 23.0.3, our project which has a prebuilt .so file in the jniLibs dir crashes in runtime with "UnstatisfiedLinkError".

Did the jniLibs location change? could not find any relevant documentation.